# How to phrase this in one sentence: developed applications and clients were satisfied with the result

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

I am in the midst of writing a job resume and would like to write one sentence that captures the following sentences:

developed applications and 
 clients were satisfied with the result (happy with the final applications).

Answer (score 1):

Developed applications to client's satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

- developed applications that satisfied clients
- satisfied clients by developing applications
- satisfied clients by developing applications that met their requirements
- satisfied clients by developing applications
  that met or exceeded their expectations
- satisfied clients by developing applications to their specifications

Comment: You could pack some of the content into an adjective: 'Designed well-received applications for clients', or even 'popular' (if there was an extended audience beyond the clients)

Answer (score 0):

"Developed applications; clients were satisfied with the result."

However, it would be even better if you included some objective metric for what kind of application, how much impact it had, and the level of satisfaction (e.g., developed applications used by 35 people on a daily basis.  Applications continue to be used 3 years later.)